# Nervous Tic: Splaying Hands

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a very specific word for the nervous tic involving splaying the hand flat, fingers outstretched as far as possible.  I have seen the word, but have lost it from my list and can’t find it online either.

It’s not a common word, and is *only* used to describe this one thing. Does anyone know it?

Comment: [jazz hands](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&sa=1&q=jazz+hands&oq=jazz+hands&gs_l=psy-ab.12...0.0.0.8270.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.mp8hWTAuVzQ)?!

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this as an answer so it stops showing up in the "Unanswered" queue.
The correct answer is above in the comments:

> jazz hands?! – Mari-Lou A Oct 19 at 5:41